# qbo3 Custom CSS Changes not Detected

Tags: css, qbo3

I am customizing a qbo3 site with CSS via Configuration > Style Sheets. However, when I make changes, those changes are not immediately reflected in the site's CSS. How do I force these changes to "take effect"?

Answer (score 0):

You likely are experiencing 3 issues.

1. Custom UI elements, includes CSS, are managed with a `CachedFile` backing store which:

- write the file to a distributed backing store (such as Amazon s3), and
- when reading the file, caches the file on the web server to speed performance

If the `CachedFile` find the file on the web server, it does not bother fetching it from the distributed store, for up to 5 minutes (by default). This `CacheDuration` can be controlled from Configuration > Modules > Attachment > Settings: `CacheDurationMinutes`.

If you set the `CacheDurationMinutes` to 0, the `CachedFile` will read from the distributed store every time.  This slows performance a bit, so it's recommended only for non-production environments.

2. The site's CSS is cached server-side for performance reasons.

To instruct the server to "clear CSS from cache", navigate to:

```
/Theme.ashx/Css?nocache=1
```

The `nocache=1` will instruct the server to rebuild the CSS and replace the cached value.

3. Everyone's browser is instructed to cache the main menu. Even after performing steps 1 and 2, users may not see the `css` changes until their browser drops the main menu from cache. They can force this by adding `&nocache=1` or `?nocache=` to anyone.